# preferences /editor there is no temporary window

Tags: interface

in Blender 2.8 in preferences /editor there is no  temporary window panel to choose from where to render results.
Why is that?[image: interface]

Comment: Which version of 2.8? - The option is certainly there in 2.83.15 which is the current LTS version available [here](https://www.blender.org/download/lts/)!

Comment: Hi :). In 2.8 and 2.81 it's not in preferences but in the main menu under *Render* dropdown.

Comment: A lifetime ago in Blender time! :^))